# transform Objective C code of a class "GPUImageRawDataOutput" to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, gpuimage

I have this Obj-C code:

What is need is to transform it to the Swift code.

(so far I did manage to rewrite C code to Swift, however, this is some kind of callback and sadly, I have not found any way to successfully transform it)

```
GPUImageRawDataOutput *rawDataOutput = [[GPUImageRawDataOutput alloc] initWithImageSize:CGSizeMake(640.0, 480.0) resultsInBGRAFormat:YES];
_rawDataOutput = rawDataOutput; // __unsafe_unretained instance variable

[rawDataOutput setNewFrameAvailableBlock:^{
    GLubyte *outputBytes = [_rawDataOutput rawBytesForImage];
    NSInteger bytesPerRow = [_rawDataOutput bytesPerRowInOutput];
    NSLog(@"Bytes per row: %d", bytesPerRow);

    NSData *dataForRawBytes = [NSData dataWithBytes:outputBytes length:/* I can't figure out how to get the length of the GLubyte pointer */];

    [_targetUIImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:dataForRawBytes]]; // An instance UIImageView

}];
```

Comment: Hi! Do you finally managed to get this working? I'm having trouble converting `outputBytes` and `bytesPerRow` to an `UIImage`.

Answer (score 1):

Coding blind from cellphone. Give it a try with some help of compiler

```
    let rawDataOutput = GPUImageRawDataOutput(CGSizeMake(640.0, 480.0),resultsInBGRAFormat:true)
    self.rawDataOutput = rawDataOutput

    rawDataOutput.setNewFrameAvailableBlock({(frame) IN
        let outputBytes = self.rawDataOutput.rawBytesForImage
        let bytesPerRow = self.rawDataOutput.bytesPerRowInOutput

        print("Bytes per row \(bytesPerRow)")

        let dataForRawBytes = NSData(bytes:outputBytes ,length:outputBytes.count)
        self.targetUIImageView.setImage(UIImage(imageWithData:dataForRawBytes))

        })
```